# Appwrite return 500 error when trying to add custom domain

Tags: appwrite

I get a 500 internal error when i try to add a custom domain to appwrite 1.2.0 server.

I have changed .env variable _APP_ENV and _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET to "api.example.com"

I have also followed manual ssl generation method [here](https://appwrite.io/docs/certificates)

When i navigate to my domain "api.example.com" i can access the console with no other issues and certificate in toolbar show connection secure certificate is valid.

However when i try to login to my app i get an error in console: Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... from origin 'https://www.mydomain.0r' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I assume this is because i am unable to set the custom domain in appwrite console but cant figure out what is causing the 500 error

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy in front of Appwrite?

Comment: What do the docker logs for the appwrite container say for the 500 error?

Comment: I too had the same error